# Fire hazard, Need to turn off power to one out of two electric baseboard heaters

Tags: electric-heat

I have a difficult situation, there is a need to turn the heater permanently off without my father/home owner 'knowing' I did this. On a daily basis he tosses paper products in front of an electric baseboard heater, that is turned up to 70* and is around 160*+ heat emanating. I am terrified of a fire when I go to work or am asleep. 
There is two heaters in the kitchen area, that are heating the kitchen + Living Room area, where a single baseboard heater that no longer works.
So if I somehow achieved shutting off the heater of concern, one remaining heater would be heating two rooms and that entire end of the house.

I have read here one might disconnect, then cap off wires. Or shutting off thermostat. And for the circuit breaker, I would "guess" there is one for at least both heaters. So these things are not a choice.

(I would like to mention am an adult. No need for unnecessary concern in to this matter further than just any ideas one might have!)

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If there are separate thermostats, then the heaters might be on separate breakers. Turning off a circuit breaker would be by far the easiest task; try that first to see if there's a dedicated breaker to the heater in question. And, I'm personally doubtful that a surface that never gets over the boiling point of water could actually ignite something.

Comment: Is there a single thermostat that controls that heater? Disconnecting the wires in the thermostat might be an option. Don't make assumptions on the breakers: baseboard heaters can draw a lot of power and that limits the number that can be on a single circuit.

Comment: FWIW the [autoignition point of paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature) seems to be 424°F. I can find some news articles about baseboard heaters causing fires from electrical cords and drapes hanging on them -- and should note, these articles tend to either say "all occupants escaped safely" or "there was no (working) smoke detector". A reminder to be sure yours work, and even if you do absolutely nothing else, it would be cheap and easy to install a battery-operated smoke detector in the room near this particular heater.